# how to get condition looked at before triggering a selectionchange event in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a way to trigger a SelectionChange event on a specific Target.Address only if another cell on the same worksheet is not empty.
the code I am using is this one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = Range("K20:M20").Address Then _
    RequestorNameEmpty

Sub RequestorNameEmpty()
    If ActiveSheet.Range("D20:H20").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Enter your name first! ")
        GoTo ExitSub
        Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("K20:M20").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value
    End If
ExitSub
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("K20:M20").Address Then RequestorNameEmpty
End Sub

Sub RequestorNameEmpty()
    If Range("D20").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Enter your name first! ")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Range("K20").Value = Range("C3").Value
    End If
End Sub
```